# std::list iterator using -> (arrow) and . (dot) produces different results

Tags: c++

I have the following code segment:

```
std::list<reply_t> l = m[index];
for (std::list<reply_t>::iterator it = l.begin(); it != l.end(); it++) {
    // do something
}
```

and

```
std::list<reply_t> *l = &(m[index]);
for (std::list<reply_t>::iterator it = l->begin(); it != l->end(); it++) {
    // do something
}
```

m is just a map with int index and list as values, ie `std:map<int, std::list<reply_t> >`.

The two versions ONLY differ in how the list is being referred to, ie one by pointer one by object. Everything else in my code is exactly identical. HOWEVER, when I run with these two versions, version 1 *consistently* fails tests and version 2 *consistently* succeeds. The code is used in a multi threaded context, if that helps.

I'm new to c++ and this is just completely bizarre to me. Anyone with an possible explanation?

Comment: How exactly does version 1 fail? How/what are you testing?

Comment: What is reply_t? Does it follow the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)? Does it make sense to copy it?

Comment: @Irfy, didn't know about the rule of three. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two examples differ in that the first creates a copy of the list returned by `m[index]`, then iterates over that copy.

To match the second version, you need to use a *reference* to the list.  Try this instead:

```
std::list<reply_t>& l = m[index]; // notice extra '&' character.
```

Comment: so c++ automatically copies an object for assignment? and you need to explicitly specify reference by address for any assignment?

Comment: C++ does not "automatically" copy objects.  The statement in your code explicitly requests a copy by initializing a new `std::list<reply_t>` object with a reference to an existing instance (e.g. the one stored at `m[index]`).  If you're confused about the syntax, I suggest you read a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242).